# mscomm oncomm event

Tags: vb6

I am in support of an application that involves serial port communication.

There are 32 MSComm controls (control array) on the form.

Suppose data arrived at one of the com port while some other code of the same thread is running (say database access etc.). will the Oncomm event procedure queed for execution or the current execution point is queed and Oncomm event handler is executed?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand what you're asking... Yes, the communication event will be queued; the code in your event handler will not be executed until the thread finishes whatever it's currently doing. Your database access will not be pre-empted.

Comment: Some database operations can be done asynchronously as well.  It isn't so much about "the thread finishing what it's doing" as it is your code returning to the program's message loop.  In VB6 this means exiting the current event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 is single threaded.  Basically (excepting ActiveX controls for a second) there's just the GUI thread.

It's sitting there waiting for an event.  You get data, so it enters the event handler for your MSComm control and starts doing some database access.  It blocks waiting for the database to respond.  Another MSComm control receives data and fires off an event.  This event just sits in the Windows event queue.  The GUI thread has to exit the event handler before it can process the other MSComm event.

Of course, in the middle of an event handler you can call `DoEvents`.  I highly suggest you rarely, if ever, do that.  It's the source of many difficult bugs, in my experience.

There are [ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to queue the long running database work onto a background thread (using a call into .NET managed code, in that case).  That will allow your event handler code to continue almost immediately without blocking, allowing it to process the next message.  To my knowledge, there's no native VB6 way to do that.

Comment: Hi scott,wht are the side effects of calling DoEvents (i am using this in Delay function)?. If we do not call DoEvents,thread is blocking the OS.Am i right?

Comment: @ramu - the OS isn't blocked.  As I said, in VB6 there is one main GUI thread.  That thread can block on any long running task or function call.  Once you execute some long running function call, you can't call DoEvents anyway, so it won't help you.  What it does let you do is pause execution of an event handler in order to process other events.  Usually this is the sign of a poorly thought out design.  You can normally replace this with a `Timer` (your Delay included) that periodically executes the work you want, and then exits its event handler when it has no more work.